# Exclude Currency Country from Script

Tags: php, currency

I  need to tweak our script slightly. What would be the modification to get the INR currency below to NOT get divided by 1.2 and NOT have the rounding occur, like the other currencies (except GBP) as per below?

```
<?php

require_once "tools.php";

function GetRate($curCode)
{


if ($curCode=="GBP")
  return 1;
if ($curCode=="USD")
  return 1.5399;
if ($curCode=="AUD")
  return 1.9838;
if ($curCode=="CAD")
  return 1.9168;
if ($curCode=="INR")
  return 1;





/* $url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=GBP&to=".$curCode;
 $s = ReadPageCURL($url);
 if ($ar = GetStringBetweenTags('rate":',',',$s))
  return floatval(trim($ar[0]));*/
 else
  return 1;
}

function Convert($s,$curCode)
{
 $path = "/home2/busi6292/public_html/orders/convertcurrency/automatic/";
 if ($curCode=="GBP")
 {
  $resFile=$path."bigcommerce_uk.xml";
  $addURL="?setCurrencyId=1";
 }
 else
 if ($curCode=="USD")
 {
  $resFile=$path."bigcommerce_usa.xml";
  $addURL="?setCurrencyId=3";
 }
 else
  if ($curCode=="INR")
 {
  $resFile=$path."bigcommerce_uk_revised2.xml";
  $addURL="?setCurrencyId=1";
 }
 else
if ($curCode=="CAD")
 {
  $addURL="?setCurrencyId=6";
  $resFile=$path."bigcommerce_canada.xml";
 }
 else
 if ($curCode=="AUD")
 {
  $addURL="?setCurrencyId=4";
  $resFile=$path."bigcommerce_australia.xml";
 }
 $curRate = GetRate($curCode);
echo ("<br>$curCode<br>$curRate<br>$resFile<Br><br>");
 $eTag=' GBP';
 $eTagLen=strlen($eTag);
 $res=$s;
 if ($curCode!="GBP")
 {
   $res=str_replace(".html]]></link>",".html".$addURL."]]></link>",$res);
   $res=str_replace("/]]></link>","/".$addURL."]]></link>",$res);

   while (($ep=strpos($res,$eTag,0))!==false)
   {
  if (@file_exists("stop.txt")) { @unlink("stop.txt"); die ("<br>stopped"); }
    $sp=$ep-1;
    while ($sp>=0)
    {
     if (substr($res,$sp,1)=="[")
     {
      $sp++;
      $lastPos=$ep+$eTagLen;
      $s1=substr($res,$sp,$lastPos-$sp);

      //pre-divide the s1 force to float and apply pre-rounding
      $preDivide = round((floatval($s1)/1.2), 2);

      //old line before pre-divison and rounding change
      //$newPrice=sprintf("%1.4f",(floatval($s1)/1.2*floatval($curRate)))." ".$curCode;
      $newPrice=sprintf("%1.4f",($preDivide*floatval($curRate)))." ".$curCode;

      //double checks the round and forces only 2 decimal places
      $roundPrice = number_format((float)$newPrice, 2, '.', '');

      //old line before pre-division and rounding change
      // $res=str_replace("[".$s1."]","[".$newPrice."]",$res);
      $res=str_replace("[".$s1."]","[".$roundPrice."]",$res); 



   file_put_contents($resFile,$res);
   $FileSize2 = filesize($resFile);
  //WriteToLog("log_".$curCode.".txt","1. sp=$sp, ep=$ep, lastPos=$lastPos, old price = $s1, newPrice = $newPrice. x1=".sprintf("%1.4f",floatval($s1)/1.2)." x0=".sprintf("%1.4f",$s1));
  //die ("s1=$s1, newPrice=$newPrice");
      break;
     }
     $sp--;
    }
  //WriteToLog("log_".$curCode.".txt","2. sp=$sp, ep=$ep, lastPos=$lastPos, old price = $s1, newPrice = $newPrice. x1=".sprintf("%1.4f",floatval($s1)/1.2)." x0=".sprintf("%1.4f",$s1));
   }
   file_put_contents($resFile,$res);
   $FileSize1 = filesize($resFile);

   if($FileSize1 == '0' || $FileSize2 == '0')
   {
    $t=@microtime(true);
    $url = "http://www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/xml.php?GSF=88d6badb/GB";
    $s = ReadPageCURL($url);
    file_put_contents("original.xml",$s);
    Convert($s,"GBP");
    Convert($s,"USD");
    Convert($s,"CAD");
    Convert($s,"AUD");
    Convert($s,"INR");
    $t=@microtime(true)-$t;
    echo "<br>Cron finished, elapsed time = ".sprintf("%1.3f",$t);
    }
  // if ($curCode!="GBP")die ("<br>abort");
  } // replace prices

}

$t=@microtime(true);
$url = "http://www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/xml.php?GSF=88d6badb/GB";
$s = ReadPageCURL($url);
file_put_contents("original.xml",$s);
Convert($s,"GBP");
Convert($s,"USD");
Convert($s,"CAD");
Convert($s,"AUD");
Convert($s,"INR");
$t=@microtime(true)-$t;
echo "<br>Cron finished, elapsed time = ".sprintf("%1.3f",$t);

?>
```

Comment: Do you wanna skip this line $preDivide = round((floatval($s1)/1.2), 2);
incase of INR

Answer (score 0):

Just Check for INR before executing the line.

```
if($curCode != "INR")
{
$preDivide = round((floatval($s1)/1.2), 2);
}
else
{
$preDivide = floatval($s1);//or whatever treatment you want to give to INR
}
```